# Constructor behavior in case of default, parameterized, copy ctor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion, assignment-operator

I was going through *Thinking in C++* and have some confusion regarding the behaviors of constructors in C++. Here is my sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
           int a;

/*Ctor 1*/           base()  { cout<<"  default"<<endl; }

/*Ctor 2*/           base(int a){ cout<<"  base::int "<<endl; }

/*Ctor 3*/           base(const base& b) { cout<<"  base::cc "<<endl; }

/*Asgn 1*/           base operator=(base b){ 
                     cout<<"  base::assignment - base"<<endl;
                     return b;
                 }

/*Asgn 2*/     /*      base operator=(int b){
                     cout<<"  base::assignment - int"<<endl;
                     return (base)b;
                 } */
};
int main()
{
    base b;
    int a = 10;
    b = a;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

[image: program output]

Could anyone please explain me the output ?
I expected just a call to

1. Default constructor.
2. Parameterized constructor.

I am unable to understand why I get a call to assignment operator and copy constructor other object being "int" type. If I uncomment "Asgn 2' I get a call to it rather that Asgn 1 which is understandable.

If I am getting a call to copy constructor (which always take object reference as its  parameter), is it because compiler casts int to base type?

Comment: Your assignment operator is wrong it should be `base& operator=(const base& b){ cout<<"  base::assignment - base"<<endl; return *this;}`. So the question isn't very interesting. Fix the assignment operator and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: @john i know, i did it intensionally. If in pasted code i change it to "base& operator=(const base& b)", compiler wont allow me to assign int to base type. I understand i get copy constructor call becuase i am passing base by value (temporary object). But i am confused why i am getting call to this assignment operator in first place?

Comment: @john The assignment operator is silly but not illegal.

Comment: @instance - You have told the compiler that it can implicitly convert an `int` to a `base` by declaring `base(int a)`. If you don't want it to do that everywhere, you should declare it `explicit base(int a)`. That limits the conversion to places where it is "explicitly" asked for.

Comment: Why the close vote? What is wrong with this question? Is there a close gang here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output

```
default
base::int 
base::assignment - base
base::cc
```

Comes about as follows:

```
base b;
```

Here create a `b` - This will use the default constructor

```
int a = 10;
b = a;
```

We have an assignment - the only one available takes a value of type `base` - so the compiler scratches its head and say "ah-ha" got a version of a constructor that can create an object of type `base` from an `int`. We can use that.

So you get the output

```
cout<<"  base::int "<<endl;
```

Now the compiler can use the assignment operator. The parameter is an object of type `base` but as it is temporary this does not need to be called (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), The assignment operator then outputs

```
cout<<"  base::assignment - base"<<endl;
```

But the assignment returns the value not as a reference - so it need to copy this return value into `b` - thus calling the copy constructor. Hence

```
cout<<"  base::cc "<<endl;
```

Comment: This description is correct but not complete, as there is a copy constructor call that is avoided.

Comment: @curiousguy - Added the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `base(int a)` is a **converting** constructor as

- it takes one argument
- it doesn't use the `explicit` keyword

A converting constructor can be used for implicit conversions:

```
void foo(base b);

void bar() {
    foo(3);
}
```

Here the `int` argument will be implicitly converted to `base` type with the converting constructor.

Because by value arguments (arguments passed by reference) are copied, the copy constructor is officially called; but here, the source of the copy is a temporary object, the implicitly created object using the `int` constructor. So the compiler is allowed to *fuse the temporary and the parameter, directly constructing the target object*. This optimisation is optional, and the compiler must still verify that the copy constructor could be called: that it is declared and accessible here (public).

Because the optimisation is very simple, almost all (or all?) compilers do it; many compilers do it at even the less aggressive optimisation levels (where most optimisations are disabled).

You declare the assignment operator as taking by a parameter by value and returning a copy (not a reference), which is quite rare (but *not* illegal):

```
/*Asgn 1*/           base operator=(base b){ 
                     cout<<"  base::assignment - base"<<endl;
                     return b;
                 }
```

This means that the copy constructor is needed to pass an argument to the assignment operator, and also for `return` instruction.

Please note that the fact it is an operator is irrelevant, you could have called it `assign`:

```
/*Asgn 1*/           base assign(base b){ 
                     cout<<"  base::assignment - base"<<endl;
                     return b;
                 }
```

and call it normally:

```
base a,b;
a.assign(b);
b.assign(base());
b.assign(base(2));
b.assign(3);
```

`a.assign(b)` will call the copy constructor to create the parameter of `assign`.

`base()` creates a temporary object using the default constructor, and `base(2)` creates one using the `int` constructor (when you explicitly create a temporary, it does *not* matter whether the constructor is a converting constructor). Then you can `assign` on the created temporary. The copy construction is avoided by the compiler by constructing directly the parameter.

In `b.assign(3)`, the creation of the temporary is implicit, and the fact the constructor is a converting constructor is relevant.

The return statement creates another copy; the usual idiom for `operator=` is:

```
type& type::operator= (const type &source) {
    copy stuff
    return *this;
}
```

A reference is bound to the target object, and no redundant copying occurs.

Comment: thanx  for detailed explanation.